# How to display a card cover completely

Tags: trello, attachment

I tried to add a card cover to my card and thought that helping the cropper would give good results. So I uploaded an image of 320x100 (see [these specs](https://trello.com/c/hshiTmEq)). The image gets cropped to a 70x50 image and only shows a very small piece of the original image.

Question: What is the size to upload if you want the complete image to be shown as a card cover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to create a 336x140 png using a Photoshop template to identify the 276x140 safe zone at the center of that image where I know cropping won't occur on the subject. It is not necessary to have a graphic of this width, but I find a wide-screen graphic to be reusable in other areas besides Trello.

I've uploaded the Trello Card Cover Preview Template to my website:
http://www.justinreinhart.com/2012/07/19/trello-card-cover-preview-template-for-photoshop/

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to set the way an image is cropped, but the default cropping ratio has since changed. It's now 276x140 instead of the old ratio of 310x100, meaning you'll be able to see more of the image. Also, smaller images are no longer stretched out to fill the width, meaning you won't get a lo-res version.